# How to eval a Tcl expression that should take a Tcl_Obj in C++

Tags: c++, tcl

In a C++ code I have a (swig generated) `Tcl_Obj*` and a string representing a simple Tcl expression like: `return [[obj get_a] + [obj get_b]]`. This looks silly, but I'm a novice in Tcl and I cannot understand how to put the two things together invoking the Tcl interpreter to have my expression evaluated with my `Tcl_Obj*`:

```
double eval(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *obj, const char * cmd) 
{
  //substiture obj in cmd and call the interpreter?
  return Tcl_GetResult(interp); //with proper checks and so on...
}
```

Am I missing the right command that does this? Many thanks!

Comment: You would need to set a variable using `Tcl_SetVar2` or something similar.

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks a lot! That looks like a way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `Tcl_Obj *` from somewhere and you want to evaluate it as an expression and get a `double` result? Use [`Tcl_ExprDoubleObj`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/ExprLongObj.htm).

```cpp
Tcl_Obj *theExpressionObj = ...; // OK, maybe an argument...
double resultValue;
int resultCode;

// Need to increase the reference count of a Tcl_Obj when you evaluate it
// whether as a Tcl script or a Tcl expression
Tcl_IncrRefCount(theExpressionObj);

resultCode = Tcl_ExprLongObj(interp, theExpressionObj, &resultValue);

// Drop the reference; _may_ deallocate or might not, but you shouldn't
// have to care (but don't use theExpressionObj after this, OK?)
Tcl_DecrRefCount(theExpressionObj);

// Need to check for an error here
if (resultCode != TCL_OK) {
    // Oh no!
    cerr << "Oh no! " << Tcl_GetResult(interp) << endl;
    // You need to handle what happens when stuff goes wrong;
    // resultValue will *not* have been written do at this point
} else {
    // resultValue has what you want now
    return resultValue;
}
```

Tcl's a thoroughly C library, so there's no RAII wrappers, but it would make a good deal of sense to use one (possibly in combination with smart pointers) to manage the `Tcl_Obj *` references for you.

Comment: Not quite: the `Tcl_Obj*` contains an object (in C++ sense), and in a string I have a Tcl command that should call the object's methods and finally return a double. I think that I first have to teach to the interpreter about the object with `Tcl_SetVar2Ex`, then I can eval the command ...but thanks a lot for the `Tcl_ExprDouble`: this looks much more efficient that the combination of `Tcl_Eval` + `Tcl_GetStringResult` + str2double conversion that I was using!